# Javascript - Merge object arrays by key, respecting assignment order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Similar to `Object.assign` where you can, for example:

```
let x = Object.assign({},{a:1},{b:2},{a:2})
//--> x = Object {a: 2, b: 2}
```

I want to be able to do something similar with merging an array of objects by key, but honoring the precedence of assignment. So given:

```
let a = [
  { fieldname: "A", value: 1 },
  { fieldname: "B", value: 2 },
  { fieldname: "C", value: 3 },
  { fieldname: "D", value: 4 }
];

let b = [
  { fieldname: "B", value: 10 },
  { fieldname: "D", value: 12 },
  { fieldname: "E", value: 14 },
];

let c = mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence(a, b);

/* -->
 c = [
  { fieldname: "A", value: 1 },
  { fieldname: "B", value: 10},
  { fieldname: "C", value: 3 },
  { fieldname: "D", value: 12 },
  { fieldname: "E", value: 14 }
];
*/
```

If I reverse the order and do `c = mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence(b, a);` the results should be:

```
/* -->
 c = [
  { fieldname: "A", value: 1 },
  { fieldname: "B", value: 2 },
  { fieldname: "C", value: 3 },
  { fieldname: "D", value: 4 },
  { fieldname: "E", value: 14 }
];
*/
```

I could manually loop through each and do the assignment but I'm looking for a more elegant/simpler/better way to implement `mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence()`. A couple of notes:

- I don't mind using `lodash` if it offers a good helper function
- These aren't huge arrays (at most 50 elements) so performance optimization isn't a major concern right now
- Better, but not strictly required, if the result doesn't mutate the original array values

  Thanks!

Comment: You could turn the arrays into objects with properties/values according to the "fieldname" and "value" entries, merge those with `Object.assign`, and then convert back to an object.

Comment: No, the values from the last argument should take precedence.

Comment: @AR the values from the last argument take precedence with `Object.assign`

Answer (score 3):

This can turn one of your arrays into an object:

```
function asObj(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(rv, nv) {
    rv[nv.fieldname] = nv.value;
    return rv;
  }, {});
}
```

Then this turns an object back into that name/value array form:

```
function asArr(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
    return { fieldname: k, value: obj[k] };
  });
}
```

So to combine:

```
let c = asArr(Object.assign(asObj(a), asObj(b)));
```

Comment: You could put `{}` as an argument before the other 2 in `Object.assign` to prevent mutation.

Comment: Slick! will try it out.

Comment: @DonovanM true, but those are basically throw-away objects anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two solutions. One using Generators, and one not:

*Using Generators*

```
mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence(key, ...sources) {
  return Array.from(new Map(function* () {
    yield* (function* () {
      for (const source of sources) {
        yield* source.map(sourceItem => [ sourceItem[ key ], Object.assign({}, sourceItem) ]);
      }
    })();
  }()).values());
}
```

This solution is awesome if you're able to use generators in your environment. It removes pretty much all unnecessary iterations of the arrays. It does not overwrite anything in the input arrays.

*No Generators*

```
mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence(key, target, ...sources) {
  const theMap = new Map(target.map(sourceItem => [sourceItem[key], Object.assign({}, sourceItem)]));

  for (const sourceArray of sources) {
    for (const sourceItem of sourceArray) {
      const mapItem = theMap.get(sourceItem[key]);

      if (mapItem !== undefined) {
        theMap.set(sourceItem[key], Object.assign({}, mapItem, sourceItem));
      } else {
        theMap.set(sourceItem[key], Object.assign({}, sourceItem));
      }
    }
  }
  return Array.from(theMap.values());
}
```

The one that doesn't use generators is a naive solution that works fine for small arrays, but I wouldn't recommend for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this issue. Its behaviour is quite similar to `Object.assign`.

```
let mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence = (target, ...sources) => {
  for(let item of [].concat(...sources)){
    let existingItem = target.find(element => element.fieldname === item.fieldname);
    if(existingItem){
      Object.assign(existingItem,item);
      continue;
    }
    target.push(item);
  }
  return target;
};

//usage
let a = [
  { fieldname: "A", value: 1 },
  { fieldname: "B", value: 2 },
  { fieldname: "C", value: 3 },
  { fieldname: "D", value: 4 }
];

let b = [
  { fieldname: "B", value: 10 },
  { fieldname: "D", value: 12 },
  { fieldname: "E", value: 14 },
];
console.log(mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence(a,b));
console.log(mergeByObjectKeyAndPrecedence(b,a));
```

Comment: I like this approach, except that `Object.assign(existingItem, item);` mutates existingItem

Comment: @AR. If you want to keep the new items intact, just replace that line with this one `target[target.indexOf(existingItem)] = item;`.

Comment: Yep, did that in an implementation, thanks. Also passed in a keyName argument so 'fieldname' isn't hard coded

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash 3.10.1

```
_.chain(a)
.indexBy('fieldname')
.merge(_.indexBy(b,'fieldname'))
.map()
.value()
```